# SSH tunnelling in Catalina to use Screen Sharing (VNC)

Tags: macos, ssh, macos-catalina, vnc

I am using the following to try and ssh tunnel to a remote machine via a master one:

```
ssh -J username1@1.2.3.4 username2@5.6.7.8 -L 5900:localhost:5900
Password:
Password:
bind [::1]:5900: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5900
Could not request local forwarding.
```

This works perfectly on Mojave (executing `vnc://localhost` afterwards in a new Terminal window). But in Catalina, no. I get: You cannot control your own screen.

About port 5900 already in use, I ran `sudo lsof -i tcp:5900` and I can't see any process using that port.

Answer (score 2):

I finally made tunnelling work in Catalina:

First `ssh -J username1@1.2.3.4 username2@5.6.7.8 -L 5901:localhost:5900`.

Then `open 'vnc://localhost:5901'` in a new Terminal window.

Comment: Using a different local port solved the problem. Thanks.