# How to install and run docker.app on EC2 Mac instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, docker, macos-catalina

I started making use of EC2 Mac instances with Catalina. In order for some services to work I need to install docker. Importantly I want to install docker only through CLI without using GUI.

I managed to install it with `brew install --cask docker`. However, it doesn't work.

When I try to run `open /Applications/Docker.app`, I get the following error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file /Applications/Docker.app.
```

Can someone advise how to fix this error? Or perhaps advise how to install docker which will not require GUI access?

Thanks

Comment: Docker on mac under the hood runs inside of a Linux VM. Since the EC2 mac is already a VM, I doubt this will ever work.

Comment: Since Mac on EC2 is so incredibly new, I would suggest that you submit a support ticket and report back on what they reply with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hearing from AWS support, it was confirmed that GUI is a must to install Mac apps.

```
$ open /Applications/Docker.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole()  failed with error -610 for the file /Applications/Docker.app
```

The above error was because installation of Docker.app requires a sequence of steps (subsequent next next options) and acknowledgements that have to be done via a GUI and unfortunately is not possible to perform via CLI. The docker app has to be installed according to the instructions provided in https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/. It is recommended to use GUI to launch applications in MacOS.

Shortly speaking, you won't be able to script anything in a programatic way. You will have to configure tools such as VNC and share the screen etc. For such an expensive AWS solution, I expected at least Docker working.

Comment: that is a problem with docker, not with AWS. Anyways, for anyone else looking to install docker you have to set up VNC. This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135006/ssh-tunnelling-in-catalina-to-use-screen-sharing-vnc